# Latex graphviz package does not accept umlauts

Tags: packages, unicode, graphs

Though graphviz' generic dot routine accepts UTF8 and in that respect also umlauts, the latex graphviz package does not. It always generates an error if an umlaut is included in a label (See https://www.overleaf.com/13308817yvjnvkfvcpxy#/51278614/ for example).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\begin{document}
\digraph{ao}{rankdir=LR; 
   a [label="Ä"]; % graphviz allows double quoted labels
   o [label=<Ö>]; % and html labels
   a->o;}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add a minimal example, not a link.

Comment: Works ok for me on mac os with tex live 2017 (after I had done `brew install graphviz`).

Comment: Can you also add the error message?

Comment: note the file at overleaf is quite different to the one you show here, please post the error message you get from _this_ file.

Comment: Well by the help of Heiko's answer I edited the Overleaf code into a working example, that has both the possibility to use double quotes with german babel and umlauts. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is caused by

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Then, the umlauts consists of active characters that unexpectedly get expanded, when the `.dot` file is written:

```
digraph ao {rankdir=LR;
a [label="\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {A\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 127 A\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor "]; o [label=<\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {O\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 127 O\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor >]; a->o;}
```

The expansion can be prevented by e-TeX's `\detokenize`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\begin{document}
\digraph{ao}{rankdir=LR;
   a [label="\detokenize{Ä}"]; % graphviz allows double quoted labels
   o [label=<\detokenize{Ö}>]; % and html labels
   a->o;}
\end{document}
```

Then, the file `ao.dot` preserves the umlauts:

```
digraph ao {rankdir=LR;
a [label="Ä"]; o [label=<Ö>]; a->o;}
```

The result:

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answer solved the problem.

Besides, It would help to reuse this answer if it were possible to add some more relevant tags. I'm not allowed to add tags like 'umlaut' or 'graphviz' that would be more appropriate.